# How I can get places with specific types using Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocode

I need all locations of type cafe, gas_station, and restaurant using Google Places Api.  Here is my query via the API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=41.104805,29.024291&radius=50000&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAVH0qHD6BPxRlnck3rIqcxC5TTwOTyfds&types=gas_station||shopping_mall
```

This returns mosque location types only. I'm not getting shopping_mall, gas_station, or restaurant types. here i am checking type in google place api

How can i get all these types?

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652543/how-can-i-search-places-with-specific-types-using-google-places-api/8657837#8657837

Comment: You can use "keyword" parameter to search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google Places API does not appear to have anything under those categories in that area.

Use `types=establishment` to get a more complete list of businesses etc. in that area.

Unfortunately, you will have to find some other way to determine what is a gas station, etc.  Google Places API does not appear to have that data, at least at this time.

It may be possible to contribute that data yourself.

Comment: thanks i get new places ok...but here every time i get 20 location is it any way to increment those locations?

Answer (score 2):

Since the answer above was posted, Google has added support for additional location types.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested in other SO thread, that you use 'keyword' instead of 'types' in your query to Google. Related SO thread:
[How can I search places with specific types using Google Places API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652543/how-can-i-search-places-with-specific-types-using-google-places-api/8657837#8657837)